# Creating setup project that update the app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

The debug of my "setup project" generated in visual studio setup wizard don't update my app when I install it untill i click on it in the explorer with right button of the mouse and use "Fix" (repair) option.

Here is how I set for the properties of my setup project:

- ProductCode> Generate a new one
- RemovePreviousVersion> True
- Version> upgarde it to higher
- DetectNewerInstall> True

How can I fix this?

Comment: Also change the Build number of your application, Major.Minor. **Build** .Release.

Comment: @MarkHall I can't find those properties, can you show me please?

Comment: You can find them in two places one is the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file the other is under the `Project Properties --> Application --> Assembly Information`.